# GitHub pages custom domain infinite redirect loop

Tags: github, dns, jekyll, github-pages

I'm having an absolute nightmare trying to setup a custom TLD domain with github pages.
For some reason `http://www` is redirecting to `http://` and then back to `http://www` over and over in an infinite redirect loop.

My settings with 123-reg are:

```
DNS ENTRY   TYPE        TARGET/DESTINATION
@           A           204.232.175.78        
www         CNAME       scottyv.me.
```

And i have a CNAME file setup correctly in my repo.
Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's working as expected for me. The "www.scottyv.me" domain redirects to simply "scottyv.me" but it stays there with out additional redirects. This is on chrome and safari on mac 10.7. Maybe something was/is cached that causing the issue on your side.

Comment: @Scotty I see you were able to solve the issue. Can you give me any hint, I'm experiencing the same redirect loop problem you mentioned, with the same config. I have an A record pointing to the Github server IP and a CNAME entry pointing to my Github repo. Any suggestions?? How were you able to resolve it??

Comment: Here I describe my working setup in detail: https://cirosantilli.com/#dns-configuration-of-ciro-santillis-website

Comment: This works perfectly for me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145231/how-to-fix-err-too-many-redirects-on-custom-github-pages-domain)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if you have solved this yet, but I had a similar problem with redirects and 123-reg. I think what you are missing is another 'www' DNS Entry that points to the IP Address defined for DNS Entry '@'.

[I wrote a quick blog post on it, with some images](http://donalfarrell.com/2012/07/13/Setting-up-GitHub-redirects.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.  In my case, my DNS was correct (Network Solutions), but I had left out the "www" in my CNAME file.  I had "yoursite.com" instead of "www.yoursite.com".  Once I added the "www", the infinite redirects were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my third Github Pages site I'm setting up and I honestly think you just need to give it some time for their configuration to properly update. It may seem like doing additional configuration helps, but in reality, it's simply that time has elapsed. It can take several hours!

For instance, my CNAME file doesn't have a `www` and it works just fine!