# How to fix ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on custom github pages domain?

Tags: dns, github-pages, cloudflare

So I had github pages set up with a custom domain without problem on namecheap a day ago. Then I tried switching to Https via github's newly added support for https on pages. After too much frustration I switched over to CloudFlare for Https but I'm now getting an error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Here's my DNS settings on CloudFlare.

[image: DNS Settings Cloudflare]

Comment: you website is working fine at the moment. Do you still have the issue? Did you try another browser?

Comment: Yeah I ended up getting it to work. I had one of my page rules set to redirect to https. Switching the redirect to http fixed it as SSL is set to full on http.

Answer (score 62):

Check your SSL setting in the Crypto tab. You should have it set to "Full". If it is set to "Flexible", then Cloudflare will use HTTP to connect to the origin, even when the client browser connects to Cloudflare over HTTPS. GitHub is probably responding with a redirect to HTTPS in this case -- not realizing that the original client is already using HTTPS, and so this redirect creates a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This problem has bothered me for hours.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought I needed to make it lower (Flexible) when it initially wasn't working. However, I discovered in the Pages setting in the GitHub repository said that it was still validating the DNS. Once that was completed, it still did not work until I moxed SSL settings back to "Full".

Answer (score 4):

More info here:
  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871

The two typical causes of redirect loop errors are:

- Cloudflare SSL options that are incompatible with your origin web
  server’s configuration, and
- Page Rule misconfiguration.

Answer (score -2):

you can update in Custom domain github pages
https://github.com/yourusername/yourusername.github.io/settings/pages

***Custom domains allow you to serve your site from a domain other than xxx.com*** with www, i was clear this issue with this way.